# A Simple Combinatorics Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have attempted to answer the following question.

Ten books are placed at random on a bookshelf. Find the probability of three given books being side by side.

My solution is $8(3!)/10!$ because there are three factorial ways to arrange the three books side by side and 8 ways to place all three in a row of ten and there are 10 factorial total permutations of all ten books.

But the answer should be $1/15$. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let We have $B_{1}\;,B_{2}\;,B_{3}\;,.......................,B_{10}$ books.

Then Total no. of arrangement of $10$ Diff. books in a row is $10!$

Now Here we arrange $3$ Given book in side by side so we will take $3-$ as a one bundle and remaining other $7$ books and arrange the $1$ bundle and $7$ books in a row

Which is $8! \times 3!$(for arranging bundle of $3$ book)

So probability $ \displaystyle = \frac{8! \times 3!}{10!} = \frac{1}{15}$

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I neglected that the other books are also arranged. Of course.

Answer (score 0):

As well as $8$ ways of picking the position of the three given books within the ten and $3!=6$ ways of ordering them, there are also $7!$ ways to order the seven non-given books.  So, the probability is
$$
\frac{8\cdot 3! \cdot 7!}{10!}=\frac{1}{15}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm glad I was somewhat on the right track at least.